# SQL Server parallels to Oracle Alter Table Set Column Unused?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle

Is there a parallel in Microsoft SQL Server (2005, preferably) for the Oracle functionality of setting a column to be unused? For example:

```
ALTER TABLE Person SET UNUSED Nickname;
```

Nothing turns up in searches, so my thought is this feature must be Oracle specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think there's anything like that in SQL server.

You could create a 1:1 relation to a new table containing the hidden columns:

```
insert into NewTable
select (keycol, Nickname) from ExistingTable

alter table ExistingTable drop column Nickname
```

That way you still have the data, but the column is in a table nobody knows about.

Alternatively, you could use column level permissions:

```
DENY SELECT (Nickname) ON ExistingTable TO domain\user
DENY SELECT (Nickname) ON ExistingTable TO public
...
```

This will return an error when someone tries to read the column.  The big disadvantage of this method is that `select *` will also fail.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent statement, but depending on your need you could probably write a trigger to roll back any changes if made.